# game slows down when I click on maximize window

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

When I click on maximize window my app slows down becose of large workspace(1080x1900);
help me to solve this problem;
my gameloop is correct or no? thanks;
ubuntu 12.04 KDE4 Qt5.1

//##########main.qml##########
    import QtQuick 2.0

```
Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    focus: true
    Tank{id: myTank; objectName: "myTank"; x: 100; y: 100}

    Timer {
        running: true
        repeat: true
        interval: 16
        onTriggered: {
            myTank.move();
        }
    }

    Keys.onUpPressed: { myTank.moveUp = true}
    Keys.onDownPressed: { myTank.moveDown = true }
    Keys.onLeftPressed: { myTank.rotateLeft = true }
    Keys.onRightPressed: { myTank.rotateRight = true }
    Keys.onReleased: {
        switch(event.key) {
        case Qt.Key_Up:
            myTank.moveUp = false
            break
        case Qt.Key_Down:
            myTank.moveDown = false
            break
        case Qt.Key_Left:
            myTank.rotateLeft = false
            break
        case Qt.Key_Right:
            myTank.rotateRight = false
        }
    }
}
```

//##########Tank.qml##########
    import QtQuick 2.0

```
Item {
    width: 30
    height: 30
    property bool rotateLeft: false
    property bool moveUp: false
    property bool rotateRight: false
    property bool moveDown: false
    property double xpos: x
    property double ypos: y
    property double rspeed: 3
    property double speed: 3
    rotation: 120
    function move() {
        if(rotateLeft) rotation -= rspeed
        else if(rotateRight) rotation += rspeed
        var diffX = speed * Math.sin(rotation * 0.0174532925);
        var diffY = speed * Math.cos(rotation * 0.0174532925)
        if(moveUp) {
            xpos += diffX
            ypos -= diffY
        } else if(moveDown) {
            xpos -= diffX
            ypos += diffY
        }
        x = xpos
        y = ypos
    }
    Image {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "qrc:///Battle_City_Tank_Player1.png"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to sets larger interval in timer object

Comment: 16 ms = 60 fps. this is simple scene for geforce 210